# how to interact with an already deployed smart contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, blockchain

I was reading this contract https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase that I found in the solidity documentation and I assume this contract is unique and deployed by the auction house. All users can make an offer. From an implementation point of view, how does a user in web3.js call the methods of this contract if he didn't deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading at the contract, there are essentially two roles:

**> Seller**: this is assigned inside the constructor, meaning that only the person who deployed this contract becomes a seller:

```
constructor() payable {
    seller = payable(msg.sender); // Contract creator becomes seller
    value = msg.value / 2;
    require((2 * value) == msg.value, "Value has to be even.");
}
```

**> Buyer:** it can be anyone who performs a purchase, as described in the function below:

```
function confirmPurchase()
    public
    inState(State.Created)
    condition(msg.value == (2 * value))
    payable
{
    emit PurchaseConfirmed();
    buyer = payable(msg.sender); // Anyone -successfully- calling this function becomes buyer
    state = State.Locked;
}
```

Once the roles are assigned, there are other functions within the contract that can be called only by the seller or buyer depending on the function modifiers (`onlyBuyer`, `onlySeller`).

Comment: thanks I want to ask you one last question. In this smart contract [link](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#blind-auction) who calls the reveal function?

Comment: Anyone can call this function as long as the bidding process has ended (onlyAfter(biddingEnd)) and during the reveal period (onlyBefore(revealEnd)). This is a commit-reveal scheme.

Comment: but is it possible to build a mechanism to call this method automatically at the end of the auction period?

Comment: Not from the smart contract directly, but you can call that method externally. If you know the end date in advance, you can have a process to call that function right at the end of the auction, or you can have a process to call the method every N minutes or hours. In essence, you need to manage that externally, but there are many different ways.

Comment: thanks I meant just that. The only way I have found is to use an alarm but I am not convinced. I am working with ethereum and web3.js for the first time so I don't have much knowledge. Could you recommend me a way to do this process automatically please?

Comment: I suggest you create a new question with your requirements and some minimal code with your attempt to do this. This way, you may receive a more detailed answer about the solution.

Comment: I asked this question [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93222/is-it-possible-to-schedule-a-transaction-to-execute-after-a-certain-amount-of-ti) but I was suggested to read an answer about the alarm clock but as I said before, this solution does not convince me. Having never worked with web3.js I don't know how to set up the code.