# Is it possible to schedule a transaction to execute after a certain amount of time in ethereum?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, transactions, blockchain, dapps

Is it possible to schedule a transaction to execute after a certain amount of time in ethereum? For example, I have a dapp where after two weeks I want to call a getRefund function on the smart contract (I already know the end date), but I don't want the user to manually execute the request. If yes how can i do it in web3.js?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I just want a function to be called at a certain time, not the whole contract

Comment: It's the same thing. That answer details how a contract can be called - via one or more of its functions - at a later time or date, without having a user manually make the call.